# SLURM environmental variables are empty

Tags: slurm

I tried to submit a job via the command line incorporating *--wrap* instead of submitting through a submission script. And for some reason none of the slurm_variables are initialized:

```
sbatch --job-name NVP --time 01:00:00 --nodes 1 --ntasks 1 --cpus-per-task 2 --wrap "echo "var1:" $SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK "var2:" $SLURM_JOB_NAME"
```

In this case both $SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK and $SLURM_JOB_NAME are empty.
Once the exact same code is submitted via a script, the variables show up.

I could not figure out what is wrong with my command line submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not escaping the variable names and those get expanded by bash before submitting the job. Try using single quotes for the wrapped command like:

```
sbatch --job-name NVP --time 01:00:00 --nodes 1 --ntasks 1 --cpus-per-task 2 --wrap 'echo "var1:" $SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK "var2:" $SLURM_JOB_NAME'
```

or if you need to use double quotes (for other variables expansion), just escape the variables with a `\` like:

```
sbatch --job-name NVP --time 01:00:00 --nodes 1 --ntasks 1 --cpus-per-task 2 --wrap "echo "var1:" \$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK "var2:" \$SLURM_JOB_NAME"
```